# How is association implemented in java?

Tags: java, oop, associations

I am trying to write a java method that discovers associations from a particular class to another classes. How can i find the association and the classes associated to a particular class?

Comment: please define "association"

Comment: Association in oop establish the relationship between two classes using through their objects. Association relationship can be one to one, One to many, many to one and many to many. For example suppose we have two classes then these two classes are said to be “has-a” relationship if both of these entities share each other’s object for some work and at the same time they can exists without each others dependency or both have their own life time.

Comment: Properties is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes because association is represented by data fields. But how can i find these fields and the classes they refer to?

Comment: @k.mariam please show us a code example of such "has-a" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a very complex question, you really should edit your question to provide more detail about what is it you're trying to do. I will attempt to explain why this is more difficult than you think while at the same time providing something that might be good enough to accomplish what you want.

My understanding is that you want to write a java method that discovers "associations" from a particular class to other classes, and that "associations" means "has-a" relationships.

**Note**: for the purposes of the example code I will use the package name "reflect.findHasARelation"

So, let's consider the following scenario:

There is a `Car` class that declares a few fields:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

public class Car {
    private Motor motor;
    private int weight;
    private FuelTank fuelTank; 
}
```

and we also have the classes `Motor` and `FuelTank` within the same package. For simplicity they do nothing.

Motor class:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

public class Motor {}
```

FuelTank class:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

public class FuelTank {}
```

Now let's write some code that analyzes the `Car` class:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class FindHasARelationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //It's not clear to me how you need to identify which classes to analyze
        // so for now this is just hardcoded for the purposes of this example.
        analyzeClass(Car.class);

    }

    public static void analyzeClass(Class classToAnalyze){
        //Process all fields of the class
        for(Field field: classToAnalyze.getDeclaredFields()){
            if(Object.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
                //Assuming you're only interested in non-primitive fields
                // this condition would tell you that the class you're 
                // analyzing is in a "has-a" relationship with whatever 
                // class the field is defined with.
                System.out.println("Class "+classToAnalyze.getName()+" has a field "
                    + field.getName() + " of type "+ field.getType().getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Class "+classToAnalyze.getName()+" has a primitive field "
                        + field.getName() + " of type "+ field.getType().getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When you run the above class you will see output like this:

```
Class reflect.findHasARelation.Car has a field motor of type reflect.findHasARelation.Motor
Class reflect.findHasARelation.Car has a primitive field weight of type int
Class reflect.findHasARelation.Car has a field fuelTank of type reflect.findHasARelation.FuelTank
```

Looks pretty good so far, right? We can see that it is able to identify that the `Car` class is in a "has-a" relationship with both `Motor` and `FuelTank`.

Here's where the complexity comes in: **What if a field's type is an interface instead of a class?**

Let's start by creating an interface:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

public interface Engine {
    public void start();
}
```

Now let's create a new kind of car:

```
package reflect.findHasARelation;

public class StandardCar {
    //Declares a field using an interface as the type
    private Engine engine;
    private int weight;
    private FuelTank fuelTank;

    public StandardCar(){
        engine = new StandardEngine();
    }
}
```

If we take the `main` method from earlier and replace `Car.class` with `StandardCar.class` then we'll see this output:

```
Class reflect.findHasARelation.StandardCar has a field engine of type reflect.findHasARelation.Engine
Class reflect.findHasARelation.StandardCar has a primitive field weight of type int
Class reflect.findHasARelation.StandardCar has a field fuelTank of type reflect.findHasARelation.FuelTank
```

Why does this happen? It's because when analyzing the class definition through [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) it's not possible to know which implementation of `Engine` will be used at runtime. Instead you can only find out that it's an `Engine` of some kind - until an instance of the class is actually created it is not known what specific kind of `Engine` it is. It could even vary between instances because we could make the engine a parameter and pass it into the constructor or a setter method if we wanted to. In that case I could have two instances of the same class which internally have different types of `Engine` implementations.

Hopefully you now understand why your question is possibly much more complex than you thought.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpfull. Actually what i am really doing is analyzing code smells and anti patterns. Some anti patterns such as Blob are characterized by thier associations with data classes. and this is what i am interested in.

Comment: Interesting idea! I hope some of my answer is helpful in getting you moving forward. Best of luck!